# Security and php

Tags: php, database, security, xss

So I have a website that given a users input it will generate a /home/content/s/a/m/p/l/e/users/profile/index.php. My real question is, is this safe? This is what I do to try to sanitize the users input, if there is more, please let me know.

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode($mysqli->real_escape_string($title)), ALLOWED_TAGS);
ALLOWED_TAGS = "<br><p><b><i><hr>";
```

Since I am relatively new to this website development, I am wondering if this is a good approach, because it takes the strain off using the database to get the same information over and over again, instead just have a static page with the information on it, or is this a HUGE security hole?  I do not know! :)  I do not know if they could do some sort of XSS attack with what I have setup here.  Please help!

Michael

P.S. If you have any answers or suggestions, could you please give me some insight into why it is.  I have a degree in computer science so I am curious on how it works, not just the quick and dirty solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Crap, ALLOWED_TAGS is = br, p, b, i, hr.  I just realized that i could not put in the actual tags :)

Comment: Better method would be to store this in the database, for later retrieval/editing, and anytime the profile info's updated, regenerate the static page. That way you retrieve a static page, relieving the strain, and still have the core data available for modification later, without having to parse it out of the html page.

Comment: Do not create stuff on your filesystem for each user, just put it in a database like the rest of the world does. Throw a cache in front of your web server if you're worried about regenerating pages too often.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but what about images?  Should i save those also to a database or put them in their own folder?

Comment: Database is the solution i'd suggest. No other way. And yes: it is a security hole. Database are safer if used well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a PHP security checklist I compiled for my company's internal knowledgebase. May be it helps.

- Do not use deprecated functions and practices
- Always validate user input
- Use place holders when using variable values in an SQL query.
- Always escape variables used in SQL queries.
- Set proper directory permissions
- Always regenerate session id when the user logs in each time. (To avoid session id hijacking)
- Never store passwords in plain text. Store only their hashed values.
- When outputting user input in a web page, always check for html special characters. (HTML tags like  may be used for XSS attacks)
- Know the specs of your deployment server before you move to it
- Protect directories where log entries are saved.
- Set register_globals to off
- PHP safe mode can be useful, but it is deprecated since version 5.3
- If not used in the code, disable the functions system and exec using the disable_functions setting in php.ini
- Set display_errors to off in production/live servers.
- Validate Cookie Data

Answer (score 1):

This XSS input validation is awful. An `html_entity_decode()` is the opposite of what you need. Further more some of these tags,  such as the `<p>` tag allow you to execute JavaScript in an [event handler](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp).   So in short this code doesn't do shit to stop xss.

You should use `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);` or [htmlpurifer](http://htmlpurifier.org/).  If you go the htmlpurifer route make sure you keep that shit up to date,  it gets bypassed every couple of weeks,  oah and htmlpurifer very computationally expensive because it uses THOUSANDS of regex's.